# Multiplying an image by a constant without loss

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing

Say I have a uint8 pixel value as [23 21 15]. I want to multiply the pixel by 12 to see it brighter. When multiplied with 12,  the resultant RGB values for this pixel is [20 252 180]. But the result should be indeed [276 252 180]. RGB accepts at most 255 so 276-256=20 is written there. Apparently 20 is darker than 255 and 23. Doesn't this cause information loss on the first red channel? How can I avoid this when multiplying a RGB value with a constant?

Comment: Multiplying by 12 will almost always be cut (for all values larger than 21), is this 12 fixed? I would believe to maximize brightness without losing information, pick the maximum value of the three channels, scale it to 255 and scale the other 2 accordingly. This way you have brighter pixel and no information loss or value cut. If the scaling has to be uniform across the image, pick the highest value across the image and choose the scaling from there. Could that be a workaround?

Comment: yes indeed it should be like as you said but another way to make the multiplication in uint16 and then revert it back to unit8? Something like? uint8(uint16(pixel)*12) . But this doesn't take into account relative intensities too.

Comment: Just casting to `uint8` would also truncate values to the least significant bits. For lossless scaling you need a one-to-one mapping. To view the result with standard s/w you also need to keep values in the usual order (min intensity at 0, max at 255). For scaling factors that keep all values within [0-255] that can be achieved, but after that you end up with either arithmetic overflow, or an effective reduced range. Either way you end up with some loss. You could try to minimize that loss with a judicious choice of non-linear mapping, but the appropriate choice depends on your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, on overflow, the color components (r, g, b) are reduced to the least significant byte. It is like You would perform a "modulo 256" operation.

You can do 2 things:

1. Retrieve the maximum color component value from all the pixels that
   you want to process, then fix the maximum multiplier in such a way,
   that the product does not exceed 255. This would be the solution to
   keep the overall aspect, it is lossless and reversible.
2. Use the min function:

   ```
   result = min(255, multiplier * color_component)
   ```

   This may result in distorted image values. It is NOT reversible,
   since anything above 255 will be cut down to 255.